# Jaya and Vijaya - why 3 or 7 births?

Tags: vishnu

When Jaya and Vijaya were cursed by the Sanat Kumaras at the gateway of Vaikunthaloka, Shri Vishnu appeared before them and the gatekeepers requested Shri Vishnu to lift the curse of the Kumaras. Shri Vishnu says that curse of Kumaras cannot be reverted. Instead, He gives Jaya and Vijaya two options

Ref: [ISKCON](https://iskcondesiretree.com/profiles/blogs/story-of-three-births-of-jay-and-vijay-who-were-gatekeepers-of)

Option 1: 7 births as devotee of vishnu in Earth

option 2: 3 births as enemy of vishnu in Earth

My Question:
Why Lord Vishnu coined *number "7" for good* and *number "3" for bad*
Vishnu won't choose numbers randomly there should be a reason behind those two numbers could you explain those?

Comment: This 7 & 3 has large number of meanings!